# Use sub application in IIS with specific domain name

Tags: iis, subdomain, virtualhost

I have a default website with a wild card certificate (*.mydomain.com).
Under the default website, I have my website(s) running. It looks like this:

```
Default website
-- Website1
-- Website2
```

How can I make **website1** available with ***website1.mydomain.com** instead of **website1.mydomain.com/website1** ?

Comment: IIS has its own logic, and only sites can choose the domain names, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis So your description above shows a desire to go against IIS design and you should think twice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't set domain name for sub application directly.

But you could just **create an another website**  named website1 with binding https://website1.mydomain.com and rewrite it to website1.mydomain.com/website1 with IIS URL rewrite rule.

So that your client would access website1.mydomain.com/website1 via website1.mydomain.com

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing